# Custom Mute Button for Audio Embedding?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, embed

I'm trying to set up a custom mute button for the embed tag.

```
<embed src="intro.mp3" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">
```

Is there a way to do this via JS?

This worked for the audio tag:

```
document.getElementById('audio').muted = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, [there is no muted attribute for embed elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-embed-element). If you want control over the volume you'll need to use the [audio element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#the-audio-element) or a proprietary plugin that you can pass parameters to.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously an old question, but I had a similar issue... probably not the best solution, but I just placed the embed in a div and removed that div on the 'mutebutton' click, then hid the mute button:

```
<a href="#" id="mutebutton">mute</a>

<div id="soundDiv"><embed...></embed></div>

$("#mutebutton").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            var div = document.getElementById("soundDiv");
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        });
```

I'm still a noob, so this may not work for you.  But it did for me!