# Mute and Unmute background sound

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am playing alert sound in the monitoring page of my site based on some condition . 
For playing the alert am using ::

```
$('body').append('<embed src="'+alerts+'" id="beapImg" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">');
```

Now i want to include a button which should mute the alert sound . I have explored a little on the below :

[Custom Mute Button for Audio Embedding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848973/custom-mute-button-for-audio-embedding)

[How to mute an html5 video player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376450/how-to-mute-an-html5-video-player)

I also tried to remove the attribute : "**autostart** " of  tag :

```
if($("#mute").is(':checked')){

    $('#beapImg').attr("autostart",false);
}else{
    $('#beapImg').attr("autostart",true);
}
```

But it doesn't help me , can any one please advice me what should i do to mute and unmute the sound .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the loop.

```
if($("#mute").is(':checked')){
$('#beapImg').removeAttr("loop");
}
```

Comment: sorry actually i dont know how to make a fiddle .. please tell me what you required i ll produce it

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the embed from the page if muted - in a container other than body

```
$('#soundDiv').html('<embed src="'+alerts+'" id="beapImg" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">');

$("#mute").on("click",function() {
  $('#soundDiv').empty();
});
```

or

```
var sound = $('<embed src="'+alerts+'" id="beapImg" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">');
$('#soundDiv').append(sound);
$("#mute").on("click",function() {
  if($("#mute").is(':checked') $('#soundDiv').empty();
  else $('#soundDiv').append(sound);
});
```

Comment: thanks i tried the above , but its not removing the alert immediately , its waiting for the loop to finish and , when am enable the sound am hearing 2 alerts