# (Javascript) How can I make a mute button to mute my background music on click?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now on my site, (http://www.thehistoryofhiphop.net), I am trying to make my mute button functional. I want it to mute the background music that I have playing. How can I make it mute on click of the image? 
Here's my html for the music:

```
<embed src="no_joke.mp3" loop="true" autostart="true" hidden="true" id="music"/>
```

Comment: why not just mute the video's sound in some video editor, it's easy like 1,2,3

Comment: @num8er The OP probably wants the user to be able to control the sound with a button.

Comment: Show the code that you are using to play the background music and anything you tried.

Comment: @Andrew Just updated showing the code. Would love some help, thanks.

Comment: According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848973/custom-mute-button-for-audio-embedding. There is no way to mute `<embed>` elements. You should probably use `<audio>`. Is HTML5 ok?

Comment: @Andrew That's good to know, yeah HTML5.

Comment: @user3925841 Oh, num8er just posted a good answer on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`embed` tag has no `muted` attribute, so use `audio` tag.

and take this code:

```html
<script>
function toggleSound() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for(var e = 0; e < elements.length; elements[e].muted = !elements[e].muted, e++);
}
</script>

<button onclick="toggleSound()">TOGGLE SOUND</button>

<audio 
       src="http://www.thehistoryofhiphop.net/no_joke.mp3" 
       preload="auto" 
       loop="true" 
       autoplay="true" 
       id="music">
```